# Why some sides of the border of a node are getting cropped in `standalone` class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, border

IMPORTANT EDIT: such output is rendered in Adobe Acrobat and TeXworks (0.6.3).

---

If you look closely at the output, the right border is either missing or barely seen compared to the left border. What can this be? (open image url in another window to see it zoomed-in)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{150pt}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % change line width to 1pt and it will still be slightly narrower on the right side
    \path node[draw=red,line width=0.01pt,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
 {\begin{varwidth}{140pt}This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. This is sentence 6. This is sentence 7. This is sentence 8.\end{varwidth}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
% you can disable following line with following varwidth environment but the border will still be cropped due to varwidth environment inside the node
\the\textwidth
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: It turns out, when you remove `varwidth` altogether, not only the right border but also the bottom border disappears (I deleted all sentences past 2nd, the node would've been too long otherwise):

[image]

Comment: A line width of 0.01 pt takes approximatively 0.13 pixels on screen (96×10×0.01/72.27) at zoom factor 10, assuming a screen resolution of 96 dpi. I bet what you are seeing are sampling artefacts.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the outer varwidth. varwidth has a variable width: it adjust to the content, in this case to the width of the tikz picture as this is the largest object.

Comment: yes I know, but you seem somehow to expect that it enlarges the borders, but in your example it  has no effect on the size of the tikzpicture, as the picture is the largest object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because observed result is dependent on used pdf viewers (it resolution) and not to used latex code. so the question (to my opinion) not fall within scope of TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: @bp2017 It doesn't work this way. Whether a line that should occupy *less than one pixel* on screen is visible can subtly depend on where the line happens to be and how the viewer is implemented. Sampling artifact.

Comment: @bp2017 Exercise: suppose that 10 parallel lines in 10 different colors are so thin and close to each other that they all “fall” under the same screen pixel (in width or height, that doesn't matter). How is the viewer supposed to render them without you claiming there is a bug?

Comment: @bp2017 What is it that you don't understand when I write “can subtly depend on where the line happens to be and how the viewer is implemented”? Besides, with a line that is less than one pixel wide on screen (given the zoom level), what is “correct” rendering is quite subjective.

Comment: @bp2017 Your calling it wrong doesn't make it wrong. Depending on the screen dpi and zoom factor (let's take the example from my first comment), in the case you pretend the rendering is correct, 100% of the surface covered by a given pixel is filled in red, whereas correct rendering would make it only 13% (which is impossible, of course). So, your so-called “correct rendering” is incorrect on 87% of the surface covered by a pixel. If you want to see the lines, use larger line widths or render at a higher dpi!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see it with up-to-date TeXLive 2019:

[image]

My filelist:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
     pgf.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
 ***********
```

Comment: compare my filelist with your. You get it at the end of the log with `\listfiles` in your preamble.

Comment: compare with my (MikteX) file list show, that i heave more recent `tikz (3.1.2). in my result is not seen any red lines looking in Sumatra, but clear visible in Acrobat reader DC (300 pixel/inch).

Comment: then it is a viewer problem. On my Linux machine all viewers can show it.

Comment: @bp2017: Then it is a viewer problem ...

Comment: MiKTeX and TeXworks have nothing to do with the LaTeX run. MiKTeX is a distribution and TeXworks is an editor.